# Q: better practice on folder structure arrangement in R

Tags: r

For tidy arrangement of file structure, I tend to place all the R Scripts under the `R` subfolder, and images under `img`. But it also cause a trivious problem that I have to remember I am working under `R`, instead of current working directory. The issue becomes obvious when working with `shiny`

Here is a toy sample structure

```
WD
 +--R
 +--IMG
```

When writing code, it's all fine, because I am editing/testing under working directory. But when actual running, the working directory will be at where the `app.R` located, therefore the path of images will change from `IMG/0001.jpg` to `../IMG/000.jpg`. I have spent hours from time to time to figure out why my single line code works fine, but the whole script doesn't work as expected, and always pops out `no such file`.

Wondering besides the `add-abs-path` way, is there another easy way to code as `in-the-same-directory` but not losing the tidy structure?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some kind of `smartPath` function taking a path parameter and change it depending if running in Shiny or not

```
smartPath <- function(path) {
  if(isNamespaceLoaded("shiny")&&(shiny::isRunning())) {
    # TODO change path to the one in shiny mode
    path <- path 
  } else {
    # TODO change path in normal mode
    path <- path
  }
  path
}
```

Comment: many thanks! It can be expanded to many other applications. Great!